# RedLaser and PhoneGap plugin

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on a project using Sencha Touch 2.0 and PhoneGap.

I need to implement a QR code reader, the client would like to use RedLaser.

My question, do you know any RedLaser plugins that work on PhoneGapor alternatively could you advice an easy to integrate QR code reader?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Barcode scanner plugin was available in phonegap

Please check these plugins

IOS
[LINK](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner)

Android 
[link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner)

BlackBerry [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/BlackBerry/BarcodeScanner)

Windows [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone/BarcodeScanner)

i think this may help you

Comment: You put the iOS link in the android plugin and the android link in the iOS plugin.

Comment: hi jcesar  Thank you .. check Now.

Comment: All of these links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use redLaser you have to create the plugin yourself.

There is a plugin for reading codes (qr, barcodes and more)

iOS

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner

android

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner

Edit: Here you have another plugin, this is for scandit sdk, if you sign up you can download an android and an iOS sample project.

http://www.scandit.com/support/getting-started-with-the-scandit-phonegap-plugin-for-ios/

Comment: Do you mean the scandit plugin? The sample project is for phonegap 2.0, and I found out they have an android plugin too.